# Array Index out of bounds exception, when I run this, I am not able to figure out why. I am not able to view the sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, exception

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sort {
    public void Countsort(int a[], int b[], int k) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        int[] c = new int[k + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            c[i] = 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
            c[a[i]] = c[a[i]] + 1;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
            c[i] = c[i] + c[i - 1];
        }

        for (int i = a.length; i <= 1; i--) {
            b[c[a[i]]] = a[i];
            c[a[i]] = c[a[i]] - 1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        int[] temp = new int[10000];
        int i = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            num = sc.nextInt();
            temp[i] = num;
            i++;
            if (num == -1) {
                break;
            }
        }

        int A[] = new int[i];

        // just a check
        for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("temp values:" + temp[i]);
        }
        // just a check ends

        for (int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) {
            A[j] = temp[j];
            System.out.println("tem copied vals:" + A[j]);
        }

        // a check for gthat a has temp values..    
        int[] B = new int[A.length];
        new Sort().Countsort(A, B, 100);

        for (i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Run count #" + i + " : " + B[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the upper bound and array access of `a` here: `for(int i=0;i<=a.length;i++){ c[a[i]]=c[a[i]]+1;` (That may not be the only problem, but it's certainly one of them...)

Comment: Please specify your input.

Comment: This code is very unreadable.

Comment: `for(int i=a.length;i<=1;i--)` looks very wrong. Perhaps you wanted `for(int i=a.length;i>=1;i--)`?

Comment: This is a certain way of causing index out of bound exception: `for(int i=0;i<=a.length;i++)`. It needs to be `<` or `!=`, but not `<=`.

Comment: This looks like a bad translation from C. Java `int[]` are initialized to zero automatically.

Comment: Start using an environment that uses some formatting rules so your code doesn't confuse readers (and possibly yourself) due to poor readability. Also, why should `a[i]` contain valid array indices?

Comment: Do not copy Java arrays by hand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your while loop should be

```
 while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            num = sc.nextInt();
            if (num == -1) {
                break; 
            }
// so that you can stop -1 to be stored
            temp[i] = num;
            i++;

        }
```

Next thing is your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { // always less than length of the array 
            c[a[i]] = c[a[i]] + 1;
        }
```